# "Search" no longer finds any results

Tags: laravel

I don't know how I don't know when, but at any moment my search engine of my application has stopped working, or rather, it no longer finds any results.

Controller

```
$request->validate([
    'search' => 'required',
]);

if($request->has('search')) {
    $key = $request->input('search');
    $searchResults = Items::whereHas('category', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 1); 
    })
    ->search($key)
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->orderByDesc('id')
    ->paginate(15);
}
```

Items.php Models

```
use App\Traits\FullTextSearch;
use FullTextSearch;

/**
 * The columns of the full text index
 */
protected $searchable = [
    'title',
    'description'
];
```

Whatever the word to search for, it does not find any results, even simply searching for "the" or "is", it does not find any results despite the fact that each post contains it both in the description and in the title.

Comment: Are you using Laravel Scout? if so, are you using Algolia, Meilisearch, Elasticsearch or something else for searching? Can you verify that your search engine actually contains the result and there's a problem within your search in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong of using `where` for search?

`$query->where($request->column, 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%");`